# How to set a square root to only be whole

Tags: math, square-root

I cant seem to find any kind of answer to this, but if I have an equation like the square root of `(X^2-4n)` where 4n is a constant, how could I set `x` so the equation gives a whole number.

I know setting x to n+1 works, but I'm looking for an algorithm that would generate all solutions.

Comment: This question belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A problem of this kind is called a [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

Comment: @Robert Dodier: This one is much simpler that would be called a Diophantine equation. It's like x*y=100.

Comment: @Pang Are the question and my answer better suited for the site now?

Answer (score 3):

So, the problem is to find all pairs of integers `(x, m)` such that:

```
sqrt(x^2 - 4n) = m
```

We have:

```
x^2 - 4n = m^2
```

or

```
x^2 - mˆ2 = 4n
```

so

```
(x + m)(x - m) = 4n
```

Now, `2` divides `4n` and so it must divide `(x+m)` or `(x-m)`. But if it divides any of them it will divide the other too. Thus `a := (x+m)/2` and `b := (x-m)/2` are both integers. Therefore

```
a*b = n
```

So, it is just a matter of factoring `n` as `a*b` in all possible ways and recover `x` and `m` from the equations above:

```
x = a + b.
m = a - b.
```

Your solution `x = n+1` corresponds to the trivial factorization `n = n*1` where `a=n` and `b=1`.

**UPDATE**

Here is an algorithm that prints all pairs `(x, m)`

1. **[Initialize]** a := n.
2. **[Check]** if `n % a = 0` then

   - `b := n / a`.
   - `print(a + b), print(a - b)`
3. **[Decrement]** a := a - 1.
4. **[End?]** if `a * a > n` go to Step 2.